# Help needed on ffmpeg zoompan filter expression syntax

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following command:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -y \
-i "https://my.domain/workspaces/473/RFP-107718.mp4" \
-i "https://my.domain/workspaces/473/margaritaville/palm_beach.png" \
-filter_complex "[0]drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=iw:h=ih:color=#FF0000@1:t=fill[padded];[0]format=yuva420p,pad=iw*2:ih*2:color=black@0,zoompan=z='if(lt(it,0),2,if(lte(pzoom,1.0),2,max(1.58,pzoom-0.005526315789473683)))':x=0:y=0:d=1:s=1920x1080[zp],[padded][zp]overlay=x='if(lt(t,3.04),t*20/3.04,20)':y='if(lt(t,3.04),t*18/3.04,18)':eval=frame[zp_stream],[1:v]scale=502:-1 [image1],[zp_stream][image1] overlay=1051.5078125:53.28906249999999:enable='between(t,0,10.048)' [overlay1]" -map "[overlay1]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:a copy "/usr/src/app/output/RFP-107718.mp4"
```

If i run it locally works without any errors, but when i run on Docker container i have the following error:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.9-0+deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://dev-cdn.connected-stories.com/workspaces/473/RFP-107718.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
    creation_time   : 2022-04-15T18:31:51.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:29.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8207 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7877 kb/s, 59.98 fps, 60 tbr, 60k tbn, 120k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-15T18:31:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-04-15T18:31:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'https://dev-cdn.connected-stories.com/workspaces/473/margaritaville/palm_beach.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1210x240 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 121:24], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> drawbox
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> format
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_zoompan_3 @ 0x40006c2500] [Eval @ 0x40018421e0] Unknown function in 'it,0),2,if(lte(pzoom,1.0),2,max(1.58,pzoom-0.005526315789473683)))'
[Parsed_zoompan_3 @ 0x40006c2500] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_zoompan_3
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!
```

My local version is 5.0.1 on mac os, the container one is 4.1.9 on ubuntu

Here the docker file:

```
FROM node:16

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y  ffmpeg \
    build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci --production --silent

CMD node src/index.js
```

Any hint to solve the issue is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: `it` is available from v4.4 onwards, so upgrade.

<s>Escape the commas, e.g.</s>

`if(lt(t,3.04),t*20/3.04,20)` becomes `if(lt(t\,3.04)\,t*20/3.04\,20)`

Comment: Hi @Gyan, thanks for the reply. I already tried that, but i have exactly the same error, although I added the single quote to the z expression, so the escaping should not be necessary.